# iCloud Entitlement to app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icloud, cloudkit

So, I've registered for Apple's Developer program just yesterday and I've added my details in Xcode.

I'm just playing around with it and following this tutorial as a learning curve if you wish (as I haven't really played much with libraries like CloudKit, Location Manager and so on):

https://thinkster.io/swift-ios-app/#saving-our-data-using-cloudkit-enabling-cloud-kit-in-our-app

If you scroll a bit, you will see that it requires to sign in with your developer's account in order to activate iCloud.

That's cool, but I get 2 errors that I can't figure out how to solve (and where to solve it):

[image: The error that I see]

I'm new to this and I tried google-ing it (of course), but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: For better understanding icloud refer http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-icloud-introduction--pre-36466

Answer (score 0):

Click Capabilities to view app services you can add to your app. From there, turn **on** the iCloud service:

[image]

[Read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) about this here

**Edit:** You may need to enable iCloud in [Member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter) too

Comment: I have turned it on already. The problems are those two exclamation marks that I can't figure out how to fix. Clicking numerous times on "Fix issues" doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I can't really tell how, but I've connected my iPhone to Xcode and clicked on "Fix issues" again it worked this time. Not sure why or how...